# Oracle - Query that only checks for a certain year

Tags: sql, oracle

Test 1

```
Date        id
01-02-2011  1
01-08-2011  1
01-04-2012  1
01-02-2013  1
01-02-2015  1
01-05-2015  1
01-06-2015  1
```

I want a query that only checks for the year like

> select Date, id from Test1 where Date like 2015;

So the output is:

```
Date        id
01-02-2015  1
01-05-2015  1
01-06-2015  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from test1
where to_char(datecol,'yyyy')= '2015'
```

Answer (score 3):

If the date column has index, the best way I can think of is

```
select * 
from test1
where Date >= to_date('01-JAN-15','DD-MON-YY') and Date < to_date('01-JAN-16','DD-MON-YY')
```